# Solved: Cannot connect to MQTT Broker over TLS/SSL using MQTTnet library

Tags: ssl, mqtt, x509certificate, mqttnet

I used MQTTnet library to connect to my server via TLS/SSL protocol but there was one issue related to configuration for **MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters** Class like this:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

My code is:

```
var caCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"certificate.crt");
var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"certificate.pfx", "12345678");

var tlsOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters
    {
         UseTls = true,
         Certificates = new List<X509Certificate>
         {
              caCert, clientCert
         },
         IgnoreCertificateRevocationErrors = true,
         IgnoreCertificateChainErrors = true,
         AllowUntrustedCertificates = true,
         SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
    };
```

Mistake exactly located in "**List<X509Certificate>**"

Whether the reason is version of MQTTnet? I am using MQTTnet v3.0.5

I followed "TLS using a client certificate" item in link https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/wiki/Client#certificate-based-authentication
but perhaps it cannot help me to solve this problem.

Pls help me to check and solve it. Thanks a lot.

**Update:**
I had upgraded MQTTnet to version 3.1.1 and the problem was solved - Maybe it's a common version for almost applications that still had used version 3.

Comment: Look closely at the example you have linked to, it is not the same as the code you have posted, you appear to be missing `()`

Comment: I also thought like that, but it's not bro. I tried to upgrade to latest version of MQTTnet and this issue was solved, but almost the other class in my code had trouble, so I decided to keep this old version. Are there any suggestion? Pls help me. The document of MQTTnet also mentions that it's support for v3, but reality it didnt work...